# How do I find the existing UIFontTextStyle of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, uifontdescriptor

I'm currently creating an extension on `UILabel` to facilitate observing dynamic type. Once a `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` is received, I'd like my selector to set the label's font by using

```
self.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(someUIFontTextStyle)
```

where `someUIFontTextStyle` uses the same `UIFontTextStyle` the label currently exhibits. I had hoped such a property would be accessible via something like `self.font.fontDescriptor.textStyle`, but the truth seems a bit more convoluted.

Is there a way to access the `UIFontTextStyle` property associated with a `UILabel`?

## Solution

```
self.font.fontDescriptor().objectForKey(UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute) as? String
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer is not quite right for swift 3. The handler for  *UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification* needs to do the following:

```
if let font = myUILable.font.fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute) as? UIFontTextStyle {
    myUILabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: font)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you discovered and [Andy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320704/how-do-i-find-the-existing-uifonttextstyle-of-a-uilabel/32321592#comment54186604_32321592), you can get the font's text style from its font descriptor:

```
self.font.fontDescriptor().objectForKey(UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute) as? String
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your solution does precisely what I needed. Alternatively, I found accessing `myLabel.font.fontDescriptor().objectForKey(UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute) as? String` will yield the same success without using a non-public key.

Comment: `UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute` is the correct key.

Comment: @Andy Thanks.  I've updated the answer and credited you.